# Where is class $tableClass defined?

Tags: php, k2, jtable

I have very little knowledge about joomla core and PHP. In order to better handle my website, I am trying to read a small part of joomla core, when I come across this function `JTable:getInstance`, (libararies\joomla\table\table.php line268), it returns

```
    return new $tableClass($db);
```

To understand what `getInstance` returns, I need to know how this `$tableClass` is defined, so I searched it in all php files in my website, although there are lots of references, even some so-called 'definitions' as [this page](http://phpcrossref.com/xref/joomla/_variables/tableClass.html) points out, none of them is what I am looking for. I am expecting something like

```
class tableClass{...}
```

Furthermore, from other php files, there are these lines:

```
$row = JTable::getInstance('K2Item', 'Table');
$row->hit($id);
```

So it looks to me, what is returned by `getInstance` should be an object that has a member `hit()`, so I am expecting something like

```
class tableClass{...
    function hit(){
    .....
    }
}
```

But this kind of code is nowhere to be found, so I am stuck here and definitely need help.

Some of my thoughts: Is $tableClass really a class? I notice that it has a `$`, which all other classes don't have? If it is not a class, then why it could be invoked like this `new $tableClass`? I really need to understand these basics but it is kind of hard to google keyword `$`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$tableClass is a variable. You won't find a class named "tableClass". It's just a placeholder for the real class name which will be generated at the beginning of the getInstance method.

Take a look at lines 268-272 where getInstance begins:

```
public static function getInstance($type, $prefix = 'JTable', $config = array())
{
    // Sanitize and prepare the table class name.
    $type       = preg_replace('/[^A-Z0-9_\.-]/i', '', $type);
    $tableClass = $prefix . ucfirst($type);
```

The first line of this defines which parameters you can pass into getInstance later.

```
 $type    The type (name) of the JTable class to get an instance of.
 $prefix  An optional prefix for the table class name.
 $config  An optional array of configuration values for the JTable object.
```

So if you look at the example you gave,

```
$row = JTable::getInstance('K2Item', 'Table');
```

"K2Item" is the name of the JTable class ($type) and "Table" is the prefix ($prefix). [$config was not set as it is only optional and probably not needed here]

Line 271 (`$type       = preg_replace('/[^A-Z0-9_\.-]/i', '', $type);`) will remove all bad characters from the $type parameter which means every character except letters (A-Z), numbers (0-9) and the characters '_', '.', and '-'. It uses a [regular expression](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDEQFjACahUKEwiE4cb4zrbHAhWGiiwKHSC6BYQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FRegular_expression&ei=wTvVVcT8L4aVsgGg9JagCA&usg=AFQjCNHpgSWfCrb96eUGShZE2vfN80Cj9Q&sig2=nfBVJ8bXoXxEJtY-DyoO9w&bvm=bv.99804247,d.bGg) for that.

In line 272 $tableClass (which will be the final class name to look after) is generated. It takes $prefix and concatenates the $type from the previous line. ucfirst() is there to convert the first letter of $type to uppercase.

Some examples:

```
JTable::getInstance('K2Item', 'Table');
```

$tableClass will become "TableK2Item"

```
JTable::getInstance('C#!ont&ent');
```

$tableClass will become JTableContent, because of the bad character removal and $prefix is "JTable" by default.

Comment: Thorough answer - well done!

Comment: For the record, a shorter pattern that will make fewer potential replacements while maintaining accuracy would be: `preg_replace('~[^\w.-]+~', '', $type);` ...if anyone wants to suggested it on github.